# Tiktok social login gives redirect URI issues

Tags: reactjs, tiktok, tiktok-api

I have created a app and wanted to integrate social login with tiktok and ability to share from my site.

i setup a app and configured everything, when I am testing the app, it shows me the redirect Uri is wrong

[image]

I'm using reactjs-social-login library for the button and configured all the scopes

this is the url generated by the APP
https://www.tiktok.com/auth/authorize?client_key=awvw5dz4j55gxgi4&scope=user.info.basic,video.publish,video.upload&state=_tiktok&redirect_uri=https://27f6-114-143-21-52.ngrok-free.app/callback/auth/&response_type=code

[image]

Im using ngrok for testing but even on my dev site url its giving the same issue.
can anyone help.